# Django template for loop iteration by distinct foreign key

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

In my app, I have 3 models: Issue, Series, and Character. The Issue model has a Series ForeignKey, and a Character ManyToManyField. Here they are simplified:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Character name', max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField('Description', max_length=500)

class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Series name', max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField('Description', max_length=500)

class Issue(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField('Issue name', max_length=200)
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Issue number')
    date = models.DateField('Cover date')
    desc = models.TextField('Description', max_length=500)
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character, blank=True)
    cover = models.FilePathField('Cover file path', path="media/images/covers")
```

I have a Character template that displays information about the character. I want to also display Issues the Character is in, sorted by Series.

```
{% extends "app/base.html" %}

{% block page-title %}{{ character.name }}{% endblock page-title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="description">
    <p>{{ character.desc }}</p>
</div>

<div class="issues">
    <h3>Issues</h3>
    {% for series in character.issue_set.all %}
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'app:series' series.id %}">{{ series.name }}</a>
        <ul>
        {% for issue in character.issue_set.all %}
            {% if issue.series.name == series.name %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'app:issue' issue.id %}"><img src="/{{ issue.cover }}" alt = "{{ series.name }}" ></a>
                <a href="{% url 'app:issue' issue.id %}"><p>Issue #{{ issue.number }}</p></a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Obviously, the way this currently formats is that for every issue in the set, it outputs the series title, and then each issue in the set.

```
<div class="issues">
    <h3>Issues</h3>
    <div>
        <a href="/series/1">Series 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/issue/1"><img src="/media/images/covers/01.jpg" alt="Series 1"></a>
                <a href="/issue/1"><p>Issue #1</p></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/issue/2"><img src="/media/images/covers/02.jpg" alt="Series 1"></a>
                <a href="/issue/2"><p>Issue #2</p></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/series/1">Series 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/issue/1"><img src="/media/images/covers/01.jpg" alt="Series 1"></a>
                <a href="/issue/1"><p>Issue #1</p></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/issue/2"><img src="/media/images/covers/02.jpg" alt="Series 1"></a>
                <a href="/issue/2"><p>Issue #2</p></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I would like to see:

```
<div class="issues">
    <h3>Issues</h3>
    <div>
        <a href="/series/1">Series 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/issue/1"><img src="/media/images/covers/01.jpg" alt="Series 1"></a>
                <a href="/issue/1"><p>Issue #1</p></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/issue/2"><img src="/media/images/covers/02.jpg" alt="Series 1"></a>
                <a href="/issue/2"><p>Issue #2</p></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've researched quite a bit on templating, and I'm not seeing a way to get a listing based on distinct values. I've also tried creating a new set in my Character or Issue model that I could use to replace `issue_set.all`, but I have yet to get it working.

**EDIT**: Upon request of marcusshep, the Character view is using the generic DetailView:

```
class CharacterView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Character
    template_name = 'app/character.html'
```

Comment: Can I see your view where you're passing the `character ` queryset to the template?

Comment: @marcusshep, updated with the view code.

Comment: So, to be clear you want your template to display only the characters that have a distinct name correct?

Comment: @marcusshep Sorry for the confusion, I want to display Issues the Character is in, sorted by Series.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function based view rather than a class based generic view. Reason being that your required behavior is going beyond something generic.

In your function you can build the queryset you desire instead of having to fight with the one provided by `generic.DetailView`.

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    character = Character.objects.get(id=request.GET.get("id", None))
    issues = character.issue_set.all().order_by("series__name")
    return render(request, 'app/character.html', {"issues": issues})
```

Alternatively, you can use what you already have and override the [DetailView's get_queryset() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset).

```
class CharacterView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Character
    template_name = 'app/character.html'

    def get_queryset():
        # return correct queryset
```

> The biggest problem though is that there will be more aspects that will need to use this set. For instance, I'll be adding Creators, Story Arcs, etc. they will have their own pages and will need to display related issues, sorted by series as well. It would be nice to have a solution that can be used by any of these templates without much code re-use.

This is a very common problem in all areas of programming. A very simple way to solve this would be to isolate the logic in one function and call that function whenever you need it.

```
def my_issues_query():
    # find the objects you need

def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    issues = my_issues_query()
```

You can also take advantage of pythons decorator functions. (Which is my favorite approach.)

```
def has_issues(view_function):
    def get_issues(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # find all the issues you need here
        # you'll only need to write this logic once.
        issues = Issues.objects.filter(...)
        return issues
    return get_issues

@has_issues
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # this functions namespace now contains
    # the variable `issues`.
    # which allows for the use of the query ie.
    return render(
        request, 
        "my_templates/template.html", 
        {"issues":issue}
    )
```

Comment: The biggest problem though is that there will be more aspects that will need to use this set. For instance, I'll be adding Creators, Story Arcs, etc. they will have their own pages and will need to display related issues, sorted by series as well. It would be nice to have a solution that can be used by any of these templates without much code re-use.

Comment: Yes, just write one function and call it wherever needed. see updated answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this only pass the results of `Issues` objects to the template without the `Character` object though? Maybe my head isn't quite there yet, but in my mind, you'd be giving the template the `Character` as the main object, and then pulling in the `Issues` objects through filtering by `Character`. I'm pretty new to Django, so I'm asking honestly! Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Your query can be whatever you need it to be. That part is up to you and fiddling around. You can define two or more queries in one function and return them all: `return issues, characters, anything_else_i_need`

Comment: I didn't realize you could return more than one object! So I could do this?:
`return render(request, "app/template.html", {"character": character, "issues": issues}`

Comment: If I have helped you, you might consider helping me as well by accepting my answer.